# How to show success message on form submit - ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, forms

I created a normal contact form using  tag in my view.
My submit button consists of

```
   <input name="skip_Submit" type="submit" value="Submit" />
```

When the form is submitted successfully it should show a message notification of Successful.
I tried using TempData["message"] = "Successful"; in controller and using it with if command in view but doesn't work.

Comment: Just redirect to another page with success message by using `RedirectToAction` or use `TempData.Keep("message")` to show it in view.

Answer (score 4):

in your controller, you can do this:

`ViewData["Message"] = "Success"`
and in your view you you can check if there is a message to display, and if so than display it:

`@if (ViewData["Message"] != null)
    <div>success</div>`

**or**

TempData can be used like a dictionary. Each saved value lasts for the current and the next request. Perfect for redirects.

`this.TempData["messages"] = "Success!";`

`return RedirectToAction("YourAction");`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using post method to do your updates, then return the same view after update with value in TempData or ViewBag. If you are doing update using ajax method, then make success div  visible using jquery after calling update method(it doesn't needs redirection)